# toolbar button disappearing when dialog closed

Tags: android, dialog, toolbar, menuitem

my app is fairly simple and always works IF my IOT device is up.
i need to load a popup and show the ReScan button on the toolbar if the device cannot be found.

the app preloads **IPaddress="-"** and loads 2 asyncTask(s)
 
one uses **NsdManager.DiscoveryListener** to find the mDNS name and loads the IP into **IPaddress**
this task watches to see **IPaddress** change and gets the presets from the device by JSON and sets up the UI or pops up the error dialog with instructions if not found.

**MY PROBLEM:**
when counter >= 15 , i show the "Rescan" Button on the toolbar with setMenuVisible() then popup the error dialog but when the button in the dialog is pressed to close the dialog, the "Rescan" Button disappears again. 
Also times out in about 5 seconds.

how do i get the "Rescan" Button to stay?

.

```
private  class getSettingsFromClock extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     String mlooper = IPaddress;
     Log.i(TAG, "LOG getSettingsFromClock doInBackground started ");
     int counter = 0;
     while ( mlooper.equals("-")   ) {
        mlooper = IPaddress;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 15)  // in normal operation counter never goes above 3
        {
          Log.i(TAG, "LOG getSettingsFromClock - NO IP Found, count= " + counter );

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

            setMenuVisible( true, R.id.action_rescan);  // show rescan button on toolbar

            try {       // delay is debugging only
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //scanning failed Popup Dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context );
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
            dialog.setTitle("Scan Error");

            Button button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
               }
            });
            dialog.show();

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Could Not get presets from clock. \n check Clock is on and on WiFi\n and reload app.",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
          });
               break;
        }
     }
     if( IPaddress != "-" )
     {
       // gets JSON here
     } else
     {
       // add popup - IOT Not found
     }

     // JSON starts here
     if (JSON_return != null) {
            try {
                // loads presets from JSON to UI here
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "LOG, JSON parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
     } else 
    {
      Log.e(TAG, "LOG, Could Not get JSON from Clock.");
    }
   return null;
  }
}  // end asyncTask class


 // remember to run on main thread
 // NOTE; private Menu option_Menu; declared in MainActivity
 //  ie;   setMenuVisible( true, R.id.action_rescan);
 public void setMenuVisible(boolean visible, int id) {
   if (option_Menu != null) {
     option_Menu.findItem(id).setVisible(visible);
   }
 }
```

Comment: That's not a very reliable way to modify menu items, as the options menu will be recreated from time to time, and that visibility setting on a previous instance will be lost. Instead, you could keep some flag field – e.g., `private boolean showRescan;` – then check that and set the visibility accordingly in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. When you want to change the visibility, set the flag as needed, and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: Mike M. - i did not know the menus are recreated periodically, your pointers FIXed it

Comment: Oops, I meant to say `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, not `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Looks like you knew that, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike M.  had it,  Thank You Mike 
    added onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    added **showRescan = visible;** and **invalidateOptionsMenu();** to **setMenuVisible()**
all work perfectly now.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
      try {
         if( showRescan )
         {
            option_Menu.findItem(R.id.action_rescan).setVisible( true );
         } else
         {
            option_Menu.findItem(R.id.action_rescan).setVisible( false );
         }
      }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onPrepareOptionsMenu error");
        }
     return true;
    }

  // when task is completed you can show your menu just by calling this method
  // remember to run on main thread
  //  ie;   setMenuVisible( true, R.id.action_rescan);
  public void setMenuVisible(boolean visible, int id) {
      if (option_Menu != null) {
         option_Menu.findItem(id).setVisible(visible);
         showRescan = visible;
         invalidateOptionsMenu();
     }
 }
```